# Download Docker Images without Docker

Tags: docker, docker-pull

At the Moment I have a really slow upload speed (0.01 MB/s) and I want to download a Docker image (ubuntu), but everytime it only throws the Error: Your Browser didn't send a full request in Time.

I already tried other Tools like dragmaster or frozen-image, but they give the same Error. Is it possible, to Download Docker Images (from Docker Hub) directly through the Browser?

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you can download the “tar.gz” of this image directly and then load the image with "docker load -i"

Comment: This doesnt really answer the OP question. Can you elaborate on your answer to provide the OP with a solution that can download the tar.gz directly from docker hub.......